# how to remove old data from structure data webmaster tool

Tags: seo, google-search-console, microdata, structured-data

[image: Google Webmaster tool]

How can I remove old items from Structured Data?
see attached image, want to delete old records, as its showing 2013 records which were already fixed.

Comment: I don't believe you can. Google is likely to remove these issues when it reprocesses those pages again.

Answer (score 2):

**How to debug markup implementation errors and Fix it:**

1. To investigate an issue with a specific content type, click on it and it will show you the markup errors found for that type. You can see all of them at once, or filter by error type using the tabs at the top.
2. Check to see if the markup meets the implementation guidelines for each content type.
3. Click on URLs in the table to see details about what markup has detected when Google crawled the page last and what’s missing. You’ll can also use the “Test live data” button to test your markup in the Structured Data Testing Tool.
4. Fix the issues and test the new implementation in the [**Structured Data Testing Tool**](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets). After the pages are recrawled and reprocessed, the changes will be reflected in the Structured Data dashboard.

Even if the Structured Data Testing Tool shows no errors, it might take some time until the page is re-crawled and re-processed for the changes to be reflected in the Structured Data dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Google webmaster tools is not updated real time. It takes some time for Google to re index, understand the changes, process them and bring it to webmaster tools. So your best bet in this regard will be to make sure that those errors don't exist now, and wait. It looks like you have already waited an year for this. Google webmaster tools dashboard is ever developing, and hopefully, these bugs will be fixed soon.